# Can't write back to Access DB on new machine (Windows 8)

Tags: sql, ms-access, windows-8

I have an application using ".mdb" Access DB written in VB.NET, VS 2012. 
In Windows 8, I can run it, establish a connection to the DB, read the data from DB with the "SELECT" statement, but when I try to write back data with "INSERT" or "UPDATE" statements, it gives me "syntax error".
Same application with exactly the same code runs fine in Windows 7.
What's the difference between SQL syntax in Win7 and Win8?

Comment: Ha ha. Unbelievable. The error actually is not in the SQL statement, cause I can save text and integer values. 

Windows 8 apparently comes here with default decimal separator "," (coma) not "." (dot).
So whenever I try to insert a fractional value with "." (dot) decimal separator it won't work - it doesn't recognize the string as a numerical value.

Who the hell and where in the world in computer business, is using coma for decimal separator??? 

So Microsoft has put it there as a default setting in Control Panel\Regional Settings???

Answer (score 0):

The problem here was not the version of Windows, but the decimal separator defined in Windows' "Regional Settings" control panel.

Some locales use the comma (`,`) as a decimal separator, but ACE/Jet always uses the period (`.`) as the decimal separator. Therefore on a machine configured for one of the locales that uses the comma ("French (Canada)", for instance), the following code will fail:

```csharp
using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand())
{
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
    string pi = Math.PI.ToString();  // "3,14159265358979"
    cmd.CommandText = 
            "INSERT INTO Constants (ConstantName, ConstantValue) " +
            "VALUES ('pi', " + pi + ")";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

This is yet another reason why using *parameterized queries* is a good idea, because the following code works regardless of the Regional Settings:

```csharp
using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand())
{
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = 
            "INSERT INTO Constants (ConstantName, ConstantValue) " +
            "VALUES (?, ?)";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", "pi");
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", Math.PI);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: Agreed. But nobody expected here to have coma as a default setting in  Windows 8 machine. I had 5 or 6 customers with brand new computers from the shop with Win 8 and all had the same default setting. It never happened before with XP or Windows 7. Veeery stupid....

Comment: @Christo I understand why many people might be surprised that some machines would use something other than the period (`.`) for a decimal separator, but it is by no means uncommon. As a software developer you simply must [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) the fact that there are many Windows configuration options that are beyond your control, and therefore you must try to build your code so that it won't blow up if it encounters such a configuration.